# Why is there an invalid reference in a recorded Pivot creating macro (VBA)?

Tags: vba, excel

I created this code with macro recorder to get Pivot table automatically.

But when I run this code again an error message appears:

> Run-time error 1004: Invalid reference

at this line `Workbooks("works.xlsm").Connections.Add2`.

Why is there invalid reference if this code was recorded? During the recording, I gave the name "database" for the table (R1C4:R18532C9). I use Windows 10 and Office 2016.

```
Range("D1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="database", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=Data!R1C4:R18532C9"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("database").Comment = ""
Range("D1").Select
Workbooks("works.xlsm").Connections.Add2 _
    "WorksheetConnection_works.xlsm!database", "", _
    "WORKSHEET;C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\VBS\works.xlsm", _
    "works.xlsm!database", 7, True, False
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_works.xlsm!database"), _
    Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "Statement1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Pivot").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Statement1").CubeFields("[database].[Person]")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

[The database table and the pivot results with xlCount and xlDistinctCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xjox.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Does the connection already exist when you try to add it?

Comment: Is "works.xlsm" open at the time that line is executed?

Comment: After you run your code once, your `PivotTable` is already created, and so is your `Connection`. So when you run your code for the second time, you need to refresh the `PivotCache` and afterwards refresh the `PivotTable` with the updated `PivotCache`.

Comment: @OldUgly Yes, the connection exist because I run the VBA code from this file (Works.xlsm)

Comment: @user7415397 is the workbook where this code lies and "Works.xlsm" are the same file ?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, it is open.

Comment: @Shai Rado May be it is a solution. Can you tel me how could I refresh them in the code?

Comment: @user7415397 is the workbook where you have this code is the same as "Works.xlsm" are they the same one ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes. The "Works.xlsm" has this code and has the "database" table as well. It has to create the pivot table in this workbook too.

Comment: @user7415397 so your `PivotTable`'s data source is in "database" worksheet ? which is in the same workbook as your `PivotTable` ?

Comment: @Shai Rado Yes.

Comment: @vega69 see me answer and code below, let mw know if it works now as you intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the commandtext parameter in Connections.Add2 from "works.xlsm!database" to "Data!database". It solved the problem. I edited the ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add as well.

```
LastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
      Name:="database", _
      RefersTo:="=Data!R1C4:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastCol & ""

ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _
    "WorksheetConnection_works.xlsm!database", "", _
    "WORKSHEET;C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\VBS\works.xlsm", _
    "Data!database", 7, True, False

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_works.xlsm!database"), _
    Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "Statement1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Pivot").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Statement1").CubeFields("[database].[Person]")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
End With
```

I could get the xlDistinctCount with this code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Statement1").CubeFields.GetMeasure "[database].[TT]" _
    , xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Statement1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Statement1").CubeFields("[Measures].[quantity of items - TT]")
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Statement1").PivotFields( _
    "[Measures].[quantity of items - TT]")
    .Caption = "number of distinct items – TT"
    .Function = xlDistinctCount
End With
```

I had to use the xlCount first and with this result could I get the xlDistinctCount.

Answer (score 1):

Try edited code below, explanations are inside the code as comments.

`xlDistinctCount` is untested as I have Office 2010 (it's available from Officde 2013), but should work.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoDynamicPivot()

Dim PT                  As PivotTable
Dim PTCache             As PivotCache

Dim WB                  As Workbook
Dim Sht                 As Worksheet

Dim SrcData             As Variant
Dim lRow                As Long, lCol       As Long

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = WB.Worksheets("Data") '<-- set the "Data" worksheet

lRow = Sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row '<-- modifed from "D1" to "A1" (according to PO screen-shot)
lCol = Sht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column '<-- modifed from "D1" to "A1" (according to PO screen-shot)

' set the Named Range "database" to the data in worksheet "Data"
WB.Names.Add Name:="database", RefersToR1C1:="=" & Sht.Name & "!R1C1:R" & lRow & "C" & lCol '<-- modifed to "R1C1" (according to PO screen-shot)
WB.Names("database").Comment = ""

 ' Determine the data range you want for your Pivot Cache
Set SrcData = Range("database")

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, SrcData)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PT = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Statement1") ' check if "Statement1" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PT Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Pivot" sheet, start from Cell A1
    Set PT = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot").Range("A1"), TableName:="Statement1")

     'Create the headings and row and column orientation and all of your other settings here
    With PT
        ' set "Person" as rows field
        With .PivotFields("Person")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        ' set "Month" as Filter
        With .PivotFields("Month")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        ' set "Count of Cases"
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Case"), "Count of Case", xlCount

        ' set "Distinct Count of Cases"
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Case"), "Distinct Count of Case", xlDistinctCount
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "Data" worksheet)
    PT.ChangePivotCache PTCache
    PT.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the Pivot-Table created with this code:

[image]

Comment: Where coms this part?: Workbooks("works.xlsm").Connections.Add2 It is needed for creating for .Function = xlDistinctCount.

Comment: @vega69  why do u need it ? It's just another way of getting the source data to your pivot cache. What is this function suppose to do? Which field name do you want to count ?

Comment: In the database every cases are collected by persons. If you want to count the quantity of cases by person you can use the .Function= xlCount. It means for example John Do solved 12 cases in January. But if you want to count the quantity of different cases, you have to use .Function = xlDistinctCount and it means for example John Do solved 4 different type of cases (Type1=2pcs, Type2=3pcs, Type3=3pcs, Type4=4pcs, total=12). Getting this (xlDistinctCount) you have to use Workbooks("works.xlsm").Connections.Add2

Comment: @vega69 can you share how you want your PivotTable to looks like ? the fields name ? I think what you're saying can be done without the `.Connections.Add2`

Comment: At the line  Set SrcData = Range("database") It gives an error message: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed